# Java request to Spring endpoint

Tags: java, spring, httprequest

I am trying to make a request frome a Java app to another app that is written in Spring. Right now I am getting a `400`.

This is the Spring endpoint I am trying to reach:

```
@GetMapping(value="/tts/{sessionid}/{fileId}/{text}")
ResponseEntity<byte[]> getAudioFile(
        @ApiParam(value = "Wave SessionId", required = true) @PathVariable String sessionid,
        @ApiParam(value = "File id", required = true) @PathVariable Integer fileId,
        @RequestParam(value = "Text", required = true) String text
) throws Exception
```

and here is my attempt to make a valid request:

```
    private void getTtsWave(String waveId, String token, int file_id, String tts_text) {        
        try {
            URL url = new URL(this.recorderendpoint + "/api/tts/" + waveId + "/" + String.valueOf(file_id) + "/{text}?Text=" + tts_text);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            int status = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println(status);
            if (status == 200) {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    content.append(inputLine);
                }
                
                if (content != null && !content.equals("")) {
                    System.out.println(content);
                }
                
                in.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log("getTtsWave error: " + e, e.toString()); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why you have `{text}` in the end of your url since it is not treated as a path param? Maybe this is the error?

Comment: as mentioned above text is a required param, so its showing 400 bad request error

Comment: `{text}` in new URL() is a string literal but in Controller, it is a path Variable. so you need to change that to `text`.

Answer (score 1):

```
@GetMapping(value="/tts/{sessionid}/{fileId}/{text}")
ResponseEntity<byte[]> getAudioFile
```

expects that `{text}` is a `@PathVariable` but in your `getTtsWave` method you are treating it as a "static" part of your url:

```
this.recorderendpoint + "/api/tts/" + waveId + "/" + String.valueOf(file_id) + "/{text}?Text=" + tts_text
```

Moreover in your `getAudioFile` you also have a parameter:

```
@RequestParam(value = "Text", required = true) String text
```

This one parameter is the required **request** param (not **path** param)

So I believe you should change to:

```
@GetMapping(value="/tts/{sessionid}/{fileId}")
ResponseEntity<byte[]> getAudioFile(
        @ApiParam(value = "Wave SessionId", required = true) @PathVariable String sessionid,
        @ApiParam(value = "File id", required = true) @PathVariable Integer fileId,
        @RequestParam(value = "Text", required = true) String text
) throws Exception
```

and construct your URL as:

```
this.recorderendpoint + "/api/tts/" + waveId + "/" + String.valueOf(file_id) + "?Text=" + tts_text
```